# How do I loop javascript function on jquery after insert new row?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I had try to show the calculation of each row after the user enter the num1 and select the num2
The current result can only showed in first row but I want after add new row

Requesting the resolution.

Thanks

Here is my code for the table row :

```
<form id="insert_form" method="post" action="">
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_field">
<tr>
<th>Num 1</th>
<th>Num 2</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Add or Remove</th></tr>
<tr><td><input class="form-control"  name="num1[]" type="number" id="num1" ></td>
<td><select class="form-control" name="num2[]" type="text" id="num2" onchange="calc()">
    <option value="a" id="a">day a</option>
    <option value="b" id="b">day b</option>
     <option value="c" id="c">day c</option></select></td>
<td><input  name="rate[]" type="number" id="rate" ></td>
<td><input  name="amount[]" type="number" id="amount" ></td>
<td><input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="add"></td></tr>
</table>                
<input" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save Data">
```

Code to create a new row:

```
<script>        
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var repeat =    '<tr><td><input class="form-control"  name="num1[]" type="number" id="num1" ></td><td><select class="form-control" name="num2[]" type="text" id="num2" onchange="calc()"><option value="a" id="a">day a</option><option value="b" id="b">day b</option><option value="c" id="c">day c</option></select></td><td><input class="form-control"  name="rate[]" type="text" id="rate" ></td><td><input class="form-control"  name="amount[]" type="amount" id="amount" ></td><td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="remove" id="remove" value="remove"></td></tr>';       

            $("#add").click(function()
            {
                $("#table_field").append(repeat);   
            });

            $("#table_field").on('click', '#remove',function()
            {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });         
        }); 
    </script>
```

javascript code to calculate:

```
<script>
function calc() {
    var aa = parseFloat(document.querySelector("#num1").value);
    var bb = document.querySelector("#num2").value; 
    var amount;
    var rate;
    if (bb == "a") { 
        rate = 10; amount = rate * aa;
    } else if (bb == "b") { 
        rate = 20; amount = rate * aa;
    } else if (bb == "c") { 
rate = 30; amount = rate * aa;
    }
    document.getElementById("rate").value = rate;
    document.getElementById("amount").value = amount;
}
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use same `ids` for mutliple elements . Instead use `name` attribute of inputs and whenever your function gets called pass `this` as well inside it . Here , `this` refer to current select box where change event has been occur then use that to get all inputs value and add new value to your *rate* and *amount* inputs

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var repeat = '<tr><td><input class="form-control"  name="num1[]" type="number"  ></td><td><select class="form-control" name="num2[]" type="text"  onchange="calc(this)"><option value="a" id="a">day a</option><option value="b" id="b">day b</option><option value="c" id="c">day c</option></select></td><td><input class="form-control"  name="rate[]" type="text"  ></td><td><input class="form-control"  name="amount[]" type="amount"  ></td><td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="remove" value="remove"></td></tr>';

  $("#add").click(function() {
    $("#table_field").append(repeat);
  });

  $("#table_field").on('click', '#remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
});

function calc(el) {
  //get num1 field value
  var aa = parseFloat($(el).closest('tr').find('[name*=num1]').val());
  var amount;
  var rate;
  //compare
  if (el.value == "a") {
    rate = 10;
    amount = rate * aa;
  } else if (el.value == "b") {
    rate = 20;
    amount = rate * aa;
  } else if (el.value == "c") {
    rate = 30;
    amount = rate * aa;
  }
  //find rate and amout and add value there
  $(el).closest('tr').find('[name*=rate]').val(rate);
  $(el).closest('tr').find('[name*=amount]').val(amount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="insert_form" method="post" action="">
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="table_field">
    <tr>
      <th>Num 1</th>
      <th>Num 2</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Add or Remove</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control" name="num1[]" type="number" id="num1"></td>
      <td>
        <!--pass this as well-->
        <select class="form-control" name="num2[]" type="text" id="num2" onchange="calc(this)">
          <option value="a" id="a">day a</option>
          <option value="b" id="b">day b</option>
          <option value="c" id="c">day c</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input name="rate[]" type="number" id="rate"></td>
      <td><input name="amount[]" type="number" id="amount"></td>
      <td><input type="button" name="add" id="add" value="add"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input " type="submit " name="save " id="save " value="Save Data ">
```